# How to fix it Attempted to read past end of byte buffer -- in module (veins::VeinsInetManager) Highway.veinsManager (id=2), at t=0s,

Tags: veins, sumo

I'm simulating using the MODE4 example inside the simulte I built, where veins 5.2, inet3.6.6, have the following error

Attempted to read past end of byte buffer -- in module (veins::VeinsInetManager) Highway.veinsManager (id=2), at t=0s, event #1

[image: error]

Comment: Can you reproduce this in Instant Veins?

Comment: Yes, it can be implemented in Instant Veins. Now it has been solved. It is a problem during the connection with sumo